# Copying aspnet app content to wwwroot inside container (IIS,windows) works fine, mapping the same directory content to wwwroot returns 401

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, docker, iis, docker-compose

When copying the application content into the container, it works. But if rather than copying, the folder is mapped to the folder in the host, I get 401 from IIS.

So, this works

```
# Dockerfile
FROM microsoft/aspnet

COPY ./src/publish/ /inetpub/wwwroot

# ---------------------------------

# docker-compose.yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  webapp:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

Browse to localhost:8080, OK.

Now, the following fails:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM microsoft/aspnet

# ----------------------------

# docker-compose.yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  webapp:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:80"   
    volumes:
      - ./src/publish/:C:/inetpub/wwwroot
```

Browse to localhost:8080, I get 401.

I inspect the content of wwwroot in the container, and I see the same content in both cases, as expected.
The IIS logs (inetpub/logs) only shows 401, no further info.

What am I missing?

Comment: IIS is rather sensitive on how the underlying file system works, so Docker's mapping can easily break it. Stick to what's working please.

Comment: Thanks @LexLi. To setup a decent dev environment I'd need to be able to reflect changes made to code, into the container. I don't want to have to build the image every time for every change. Also, both host and container use Windows, so no big difference should be found.
Anyway, if this doesn't work then I'd consider it a bug, and a big important one, because it takes away the chance to develop in this fashion. Were you able to reproduce it as well?

Comment: If you can reproduce it, then that issue must be reproducible on more than a bunch of machines than yours. So trying to reproduce it isn't meaningful at all. Like I said, make no assumption that "no big difference should be found", as Docker hides the actual file system implementation from you. Even if you think that's a bug, it won't be fixed soon (Docker on Windows falls behind most of the time).

Comment: Yes, it would be meaningful because in the first place I want to make sure it's not MY mistake, and it is ACTUALLY a bug, and this is the purpose of me throwing the question: Am I making a dumb mistake somewhere, or is it that this just doesn't work (a bug)? (this is so basic that I find it hard to believe that it just doesn't work... which by the way surprises me how easily you seem to accept it like BAU ¡¿?!) (also, the 'stick to what works' is an obvious approach... I'm sure you are sure I didn't overlooked it, right?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not missing anything. It's an IIS issue.